# Input button Id Not Working when I put Div as JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```html
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <img class="modal-title" src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/img/logo-small.png" alt="person">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal",><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <form class="card card-sm">
                                        <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                            <!--end of col-->
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="search" placeholder="Search a Product">
                                            </div>
                                            <!--end of col-->
                                            <div class="col-auto">
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--end of col-->
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <!--end of col-->
                            </div>
    <div class="row" id="allProduct">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#prod_detail').click(function(){
    $('#allProduct').html(" ");

       $.ajax({
           url:"shop/Compare/getProduct",
           method: "POST",
           contentType: "json", 
           dataType:"JSON",
           success:function(data)
           {   
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    var name=data[i][0].product_description;
                    var pic=data[i][0].product_pic;
                    var cat=data[i][0].catagory;
                    var id=data[i][0].product_id;
                    var div= ['<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px; "> ',
                        '<figure class="card card-product text-center" ',
                          '<div class="img-wrap">',
                            '<a >',
                               '   <img height="200" width="200" src="http://localhost/fyp/uploads/product/'+pic+'" > ',
                                   '<figcaption class="info-wrap">',
                                  ' <h2  class="title">'+name+'</h2>',
                                  ' <h2  class="desc">'+cat+'</h2>',
                                  '<input type="button"  id="selectedProduct" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Select" >',
                                  '</a>',
                                  '</figcaption>',
                                  '</div>',

                                  '</figure>',
                                  '</div>'].join(' ');
                                  $("#allProduct").append(div);
                }
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
            }
       });
       $('#selectproduct').modal('show');

});
</script>
```

Appending Div #allproduct div another div by Making it as javascript String #all product id a div in my bootstrap modal
i want to click on #selectedProduct to perform a function as

```
$('#selectedProduct').click(function(){
    window.location='google.com';
});
```

when I use same id from another button it works fine but in this case it is not working.

Comment: Duplicate IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML**. Consider fixing that first.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake in question i update it.. you can check again

Comment: You're still looping with `id="selectedProduct"`

Comment: means i have to make this id unique everytime...?

Comment: Yes. Or use classes instead.

Comment: Better to not use IDs at all, for something like this, consider classes instead

Comment: ohh ok i will try thanks for answering

Comment: now i have changed my code to

`'<input type="button"   class="btn btn-info btn-sm selectedProduct" value="Select" >',
  `
and my jquery code is now

`
`$('.selectedProduct').click(function(){
        window.location='google.com';
        
    });`

Comment: its still not worling

Comment: `$('#allProduct').on('click','.selectedProduct',function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location='google.com';
        
    });`

Comment: my last comment worked for me thank you